# Using the HTTP API in Windows

Tags: windows, http

I have the task to build an HTTP server with the HTTP API. Can I use the HTTP API in Windows XP or Windows 7?

I cannot find `http.h` as an include header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are using old Windows SDK, as `http.h` is present in as old SDK as [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24826)

HTTP API exists in versions 1 and 2, see availability details on MSDN: [HTTP Server API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364622%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) .